# gdm3 doesn't start during boot ("session never registered")

Tags: gnome, xorg, gdm

I have `Linux syg-5 5.4.0-73-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 14 17:39:42 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`  with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome.

When I logged out today, my machine crashed for some reason, and I had to do a hard shutdown (pressing the power button for some time). Now, when I boot again, gdm3 is not started in tty1. I just see a blinking cursor in the top left. I can switch to tty2 and `startx`, and then I'm back to a working GUI. However, the login screen does not show up anymore in tty1.

`systemctl status gdm` gives:

```
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-05-20 17:08:41 CEST; 5min ago
    Process: 2175 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2202 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2208 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 47764)
     Memory: 9.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─2208 /usr/sbin/gdm3

May 20 17:09:34 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
May 20 17:09:34 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: Child process -4492 was already dead.
May 20 17:09:34 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: Child process -4492 was already dead.
May 20 17:09:34 syg-5 gdm-launch-environment][4975]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user g>
May 20 17:09:40 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
May 20 17:09:40 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server l>
May 20 17:09:40 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: Child process -4993 was already dead.
May 20 17:10:00 syg-5 gdm-launch-environment][5137]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user g>
May 20 17:10:03 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
May 20 17:10:03 syg-5 gdm3[2208]: GdmLocalDisplayFactory: maximum number of X display failures reached: check X server log
```

I also tried to reinstall gdm3 and temporarily switched to LightDM. But the problem persists.

The server log gives no errors (`cat Xorg.0.log | grep EE`   is essentially empty).

I have no idea on how to debug this. What could I do?

Comment: Have you checked tty8 or tty7?

Comment: Didn't even know they exist. In the end I completely reinstalled everything. I tried a lot, to no avail, so reinstalling was the only way.